# Calculate overall score for multiple choice form with set value for each option selected

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get an overall total for a set of multiple choice questions. Each option is assigned a numerical value.

If the total is above 50, the user will get an email advising them their application has been submitted.

So far I have been unable to generate an overall score.

I've tried many different solutions that I have found here and tried to apply them but none have worked.  Am fairly new to JavaScript which is not helping!

```js
$(":radio").on("change", function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(":radio:checked").each(function() {
    total += Number(this.value);
  });

  $("#total").text(total);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">

    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>What age band do you fit into?</h3>
        <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="25" checked="true">25 - 31<br>
        <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="25" checked="true">32 - 38<br>
        <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="25" checked="true">39 - 43<br>
      </div>
    </li>

    <p>Total Score:<span id="total">0</span></p>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please be more precise: what should this be dong under what circumstances, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: I basically have to create a form with 11 questions, all multiple choice answers. Each choice will have a score. Users will need a score over 50 for their application to be accepted. Once they score over 50,they should get an email inviting them for interview. The javascript needs to add up the score values. At the moment it's not doing anything. I have a non interactive html form! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed your script in the `<head>` tags. Moving it to below the body will load it correctly:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="">
      <li>
        <div>
          <h3>What age band do you fit into?</h3>
          <input
            class="calc"
            type="radio"
            name="radio1"
            value="25"
            checked="true"
          />25 - 31<br />
          <input
            class="calc"
            type="radio"
            name="radio1"
            value="25"
            checked="true"
          />32 - 38<br />
          <input
            class="calc"
            type="radio"
            name="radio1"
            value="25"
            checked="true"
          />39 - 43<br />
        </div>
      </li>

      <p>Total Score:<span id="total">0</span></p>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script language="javascript">
      $(":radio").on("change", function() {
        var total = 0;
        $(":radio:checked").each(function() {
          total += Number(this.value);
        });

        $("#total").text(total);
      });
   </script>
   
</html>
```

Comment: No problem, it was just the position of the code, that's all 

Answer (score 0):

A quick example of what I believe you are trying to accomplish here. Simply store the value you add, and then subtract it from the total before adding a new one.

```js
  (function () {
            var group = document.forms.myForm.elements.add;
            var currentValue = function currentValue () {
                for (var i = 0, j = group.length; i < j; i++) {
                    if (group[i].checked) {
                        return Number(group[i].value);
                    }
                }
            };
            var oldValue = currentValue();
            var total = document.getElementById('total').firstChild;

            var update = function update () {
                var current = currentValue();
                total.data = Number(total.data) - oldValue + current;
                oldValue = current;
            };

            for (var i = 0, j = group.length; i < j; i++) {
                group[i].onchange = update;
            }
        }());
```

```html
    <form action="" method="get" id="myForm">
        <fieldset id="myRadioGroup">
            <legend>Which Age Band do You Fit Into?</legend>
            <div>
                <label> <input type="radio" value="0" name="add" checked> 25 - 31 </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label> <input type="radio" value="20" name="add"> 32 - 38 </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label> <input type="radio" value="30" name="add"> 39 - 43 </label>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>

        <div id="total">0</div>
```

Comment: Hi and thank you so much for your help!  This works really well.  If you don't mind, I have a follow up? When I add a second question, and choose an answer, the code displays the score for that choice.  I need the choice from the first and second question to add together.  I've tried changing the line " total.data = Number(total.data) - oldValue + current;" to " total.data = Number(total.data) + oldValue + current;".  This is adding the totals, but if i go back and change the choice, it adds that score too?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="">
      <li>
        <div>
          <h3>What age band do you fit into?</h3>
          <input
            class="calc"
            type="radio"
            name="radio1"
            value="25"
            checked="true"
          />25 - 31<br />
          <input
            class="calc"
            type="radio"
            name="radio1"
            value="25"
            checked="true"
          />32 - 38<br />
          <input
            class="calc"
            type="radio"
            name="radio1"
            value="25"
            checked="true"
          />39 - 43<br />
        </div>
      </li>

      <p>Total Score:<span id="total">0</span></p>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script language="javascript">
      $(":radio").on("change", function() {
        var total = 0;
        $(":radio:checked").each(function() {
          total += Number(this.value);
        });

        $("#total").text(total);
      });
   </script>
   
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).